# Convert string to modified digit

Tags: python

I have the following numbers, which I want to convert:

```
'2.44' --> '2.44'
'12.83' --> '2.83'
'121.834' --> '1.83'
```

In other words, I want 1 digit to the left of the decimal point and two digits to the right. What would be the best way to do this? My current method is using:

```
number = '41.33'
index = number.index('.')
result = number[index-1] + '.' + number[index+1:index+3]
```

Is there a better, cleaner way to do this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
result = number[index - 1: index + 3]
```

that is all

Comment: simplest and most efficient

Answer (score 8):

You can use regex:

```
>>> print(re.search(r'\d\.\d\d', '121.834').group())
1.83
```

Comment: and now you dont even need index

Comment: I think regex is a bit heavy here. But anyway - `re.findall('\d\.\d\d', s)[0]` works too

Answer (score 3):

You can make use of the `round` function and modulo arithmetic.

```
result = str(round(float(number) % 10, 2))
```

Quick explanation: `float(number) % 10` gets rid of anything before the first digit. `round(x, 2)` gets rid of anything after the second two. `str` and `float` are for typecasting.

Answer (score 1):

```
left, dot, right = number.partition('.')
result = left[-1:] + dot + right[:2]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
a=[2.44,12.83,121.834]
for x in a:
    print (re.search('\d\.\d\d', '{}'.format(x)).group())
```

Output:

```
>>> 
2.44
2.83
1.83
>>>
```

It was what Im going to write, how ever Rawing gave the answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
result = round(float(number[index-1:]),2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a method that uses re.sub:

```
print(re.sub('^.*?(.\..*)', r'\1', string))
```

r'\1' specifies the capture group you wish to keep.